# Word for the removal of a marked property

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice

The use-case I'm working with is pretty simple. A record can be marked as deleted or removed by a method I named *mark_deleted*. However I can't find a good word for the reverse, the closest I've come is simply *unmark* but I feel like there should be a better option.

Comment: At that point aren’t you just ***keeping*** the record?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because choosing names, particularly program identifiers, is explicitly out of scope for our site according to our Help Center.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go for a single method that will remove the mark when is exists and add/set the mark when it doesn't and call it  *"toggle_deleted"*

The verb "to toggle" is used in computing to *switch* or *alternate* between **two** settings, conditions, functions, etc. by means of a toggle. <sup>[1](https://www.yourdictionary.com/toggle)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

If something is deleted, and you *undelete* it, what you are doing is *restoring* it.

Therefore, to me, the clearest opposite to *mark_deleted* is ***mark_restored***.

---

Of course, you could also use synonyms like *recovered*—or even *undeleted* itself, if you don't mind its non-positive sense.

This also presumes that if something is neither deleted nor restored, it has no *mark_* terminology associated with it.